# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, passport.js, bcrypt

I am trying to use postman for the first time and yes i am a beginner with this authentication. I have a register page and a login page in angular and my backend is running on another port which is coded in nodejs. So i have installed passport and other required packages for the login authentication and registering user process. But on sending request to register route for registering a user i get the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error. Even though there is then and catch inside the route it is still giving this error because of which i am confused. The data that i am sending is perfect but the error is occuring on the server side. 
Here is my app.js file that contains all the routes

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var session = require('cookie-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

var User = require('./models/User');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors());
var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000) // 1 hour
app.use(session({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2'],
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: 'example.com',
    path: 'foo/bar',
    expires: expiryDate
  }
}))
app.set('port', process.env.port || 3000);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/server", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
}, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There is error in connecting with mongodb');
  }
  console.log('Connection has been established.');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello");
});


//Trying registering with passport

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    debugger;
    const { firstname, lastname, email, password } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.render('register', {
        errors,
        name,
        email,
        password,
        password2
      });
    } else {
      User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          errors.push({ msg: 'Email already exists' });
          res.render('register', {
            errors,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            email,
            password
          });
        } else {
          const newUser = new User({
            firstname,
            lastname,
            email,
            password
          });

          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              newUser.password = hash;
              newUser
                .save()
                .then(user => {
                  req.flash(
                    'success_msg',
                    'You are now registered and can log in'
                  );
                  res.redirect('/login');
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

//end


app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/dashboard',
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
  });


app.listen(app.get('port'), function(err, response) {
    console.log("Server is running");
});
```

passport.js file in config folder

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ emailField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
      // Match user
      User.findOne({
        email: email
      }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
        }

        // Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Currently it doesn't look like you have a `catch()` on any of the `User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {` at the level equivalent to the `then()`. Have you tried adding `catch()` at that top most level? The inside most promise may not be the issue here.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky no i haven't tried it. can you please help me with a little code?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Try putting `catch()` at the same level as `then()` anywhere you are executing `User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {`. Something like `User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {/* existing code */}).catch(err => console.log(err)` to start out with.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky okay now i was able to remove this error but got this one now `Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided`

Comment: my frontend is in angular running on another port then why do i need to specify any engine here in node server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this specific issue, you need to provide a `catch()` when you execute `User.findOne()` at the same level as the outermost `then()`:

```
User.findOne({ email: email })
  .then(user => { /* existing code */})
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); // add catch()
```

And:

```
// Match user
User.findOne({ email: email })
  .then(user => { /* existing code */ })
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); // add catch()
```

Regarding the issue with the engine. You need to specify a rendering engine such as `pug` or `html` or `ejs`, this is something that Express as a framework expects. The link you provided that you are basing this code off of is using a rendering engine, specifically ejs. This is evident from the use of `res.render()`, which renders templates from the "views" folder.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Even with the rendering engine, set you don't actually need to render any templates. As long as you remove `res.render()` and instead just use `res.send()` or equivalent, you can use this Express application as an API.

If your intention is to NOT use templates but still render the built angular files, you need to update the code and remove all instances of `res.render()` and `res.redirect()`. You can instead, still setting a view engine to satisfy Express, do something along the following:

```
// towards top of file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/built/angular')));

// ...

// after all other routes
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/path/to/built/angular/index.html'));
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: but nodejs is only for backend here i am not using any html file or there is no folder for views. the frontend is in angular then why do i need to specify a rendering engine?

Comment: This is required for Express. You don’t actually need to render anything with it and have it simply be an API. But you need to provide a rendering engine, any rendering engine.

Comment: error: cannot find module 'html' 
tried ejs too but same issue :/

Comment: Okay try using pug and make sure pug non module is installed

Comment: but using jade will also require me to have a views folder and a file with .jade format and same in the case of other because the standard when adding these engines is to have a views folder and inside it all your template engine files are placed and in my case i do not need any engine. This is getting quite confusing for me :(

Comment: you can check this link [link](https://github.com/bradtraversy/node_passport_login) and see the way that i am following here

Comment: Even if **you** do not need an engine, express expects you to define an engine. That being said, both the code in the link you provided and you are actually using rendered pages. In your code you use `res.render()`, which is using a rendering engine. If you are intending for this to be purely an API that sends/receives JSON, you need to update a good portion of the code to not use `res.render()` or `res.redirect()`. Something other than express may be a better option.